# Intellij switch from sbt to maven

Tags: intellij-idea

I have an SBT project opened in Intellij.
I want to convert it to Maven.

I created a `pom.xml` file, I removed `build.sbt` and now I want Intellij to see it as a Maven project.

If I do:

`File -> New -> Project From Existing Sources`

Then Intellij won't offer me the option to open it as a Maven project.

If I select `Add Maven Project` then I am unable to choose the current directory.

So how can I make Intellij see the project as a Maven project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use File | Open..., select the pom.xml file, choose "Open as Project" in the message box that appears.